# How to locate this particular text that is present inside the div tag?

Tags: java, selenium

I have the below list of div tags and I want to select the text 'Entry' from the 3rd div tag.

```
<DIV class=menuLink style="BORDER-TOP-COLOR: transparent; BACKGROUND: #dcdfec; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: transparent; BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: transparent; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: transparent">Start Call</DIV>


<DIV class=menuLink style="BORDER-TOP-COLOR: transparent; BACKGROUND: #dcdfec; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: transparent; BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: transparent; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: transparent">Web Pay SR</DIV>


<DIV class=menuLink style="BORDER-TOP-COLOR: transparent; BACKGROUND: #dcdfec; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: transparent; BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: transparent; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: transparent">Entry</DIV>


<DIV class=menuLink style="BORDER-TOP-COLOR: transparent; BACKGROUND: #dcdfec; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: transparent; BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: transparent; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: transparent">Exit</DIV>
```

I used

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Entry")).getText();
```

I get the below error:

> Unable to find element with partial link text == Entry

Could some one please help me to sort this out. 
TIA!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _...select the text..._? Do you want to click on the element?

Answer (score 2):

Try use Webdriverwait and xpath to find dynamic element.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'Entry')]")));
element.click()
```

OR

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='menuLink'][contains(.,'Entry')]")));
element.click()
```

Or you can use linkText instead of xpath.

Comment: _Or you can use linkText instead of xpath_ ... **linkText** for a **`<DIV>`** node?

Comment: No not at all with some implicit wait :)

Answer (score 0):

As the element is a `<DIV>` element you can't use **linkText** or **partialLinkText**. Hence you see the error as:

```
Unable to find element with partial link text == Entry
```

To `click()` on the element with text as **Entry** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *elementToBeClickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='menuLink' and text()='Entry']"))).click();
  ```